# Pythonic style guide

Tags: python

Which of these 3 python snippets is more pythonic?

This 1 liner list comprehensions which is a little overcomplex

```
users_to_sent = [(my_database.get_user_by_id(x), group['num_sent'][x]) for x in user_ids]
```

or this multi liner which is 'too many lines of code'

```
users_to_sent = []
for id in user_ids:
    t1 = my_database.get_user_by_id(id)
    t2 = group['num_sent'][id]
    users_to_sent.append( (t1,t2) )
```

or should the 1 liner be spun out into a separate function and called from a list comprehension?

```
def build_tuple(x, my_database, group):
    return (my_database.get_user_by_id(x), group['num_sent'][x])

users_to_sent = [build_tuple(x, my_database, group) for x in user_ids]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd definitely need to name your function something more descriptive than `build_tuple` for it to be a good idea (and same with `t1` and `t2` in the multi-liner!).

I'd use a function if it's something you do more than once or twice, otherwise I'd probably stick with the list comprehension - I find it easier to read than the multi-liner version.

If I was doing a function, I'd probably make it generate the whole list - is there any reason not to do that?

```
def make_users_to_sent(user_ids, my_database, group):
    return [(my_database.get_user_by_id(x), group['num_sent'][x]) for x in user_ids]

users_to_sent = make_users_to_sent(user_ids, my_database, group)
```